# How to update Isotope 2 items via ajax while maintaining current sorting and filtering?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-isotope

I'm using isotope to build a cards dashboard. The card's data are generated on the fly via a controller action (MVC 5 partial view):

```
<div id="cards">
    @Html.Action("GetCards")
</div>
```

Turns into:

```
<div id="cards">
    <div id="rn" class="card w2" data-errors="1" data-warnings="2">
         ...
    </div>
    <div id="ba" class="card" data-errors="0" data-warnings="1">
         ...
    </div>
</div>
```

And this code is used to initialize Isotope 2:

```
var $isogrid = $('#cards').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.card',
    masonry: {
        columnWidth: 7 // does anyone knows how this works, I can't understand it. :P
    },
    getSortData: {
        region: '.title',
        errors: '[data-errors]',
        warnings: '[data-warnings]'
    },
    sortBy: ['errors', 'warnings', 'region'],
    sortAscending: { errors: false, warnings: false, region: true }
});
```

The cards and the masonry layout are properly displayed and everything works as intended. The problem happens when I update the cards, via ajax:

```
setInterval(function () {
    $.get('@Url.Action("GetCards")', function (data) {
        var $item = $('.card');
        $isogrid.isotope('remove', $item);

        $isogrid.append(data)
            .isotope('appended', data)
            .isotope('reloadItems').isotope('layout');
    });
}, 5000);
```

But by doing this the grid lose the layout: all cards gets stacked at the top-left corner, and the filtering and sorting settings are also lost.

**Ideally, I should just update modified cards instead of removing and reinserting them. Most of the times the same cards (with updated information) will be received, but sometimes (rarely) some cards will be removed from the list and/or new cards will be inserted.** Does anyone knows a way to achieve this?

Comment: I have the same issue, any luck?

Comment: thats great, were you able to do a `toggle-size-all` items in V2 or is this gone?                                 `$('#toggle-sizes').find('a').click(function(){
        $container
          .toggleClass('variable-sizes')
          .isotope('reLayout');
        return false;
      });`  under the Etc section [on the demo](http://bit.ly/19GXxDy) page linked. Can you post a fiddle on (https://dotnetfiddle.net) this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another question of mine that does not get answers so I must keep trying and searching until I find a solution. This one is quite specific, I'll give you that.

Anyway, isotope's methods `appended` and `prepended` where having a hard time propperly setting the layout after inserting the items. Also, adding the items via `$isogrid.append/preppend` seems kinda broken right now so I added the items to the DOM via jquery and then inserted them in Isotope and everything worked fine again:

```
setInterval(function () {
    $.get('@Url.Action("GetCards")', function (data) {
        var $item = $('.card');
        $isogrid.isotope('remove', $item);
        $('#cards').html('').append(data);
        $isogrid.isotope('insert', $('.card'));
    });
}, 5000);
```

I still can't find an easy way to update existing cards instead of replacing everything, tho, so I'll wait a couple more days before accepting this answer.